# .NET visual code (two hard disks)

Tags: c#, .net

*I have an SSD and a HDD in my laptop. I'm trying to do some C# but when I type the "dotnet new" it is unrecognised. I think the problem is that .NET is installed on C: (SSD) ,because running "dotnet" works when the command promt is on the C: drive, but my workspace folder is on the D: (HDD) so it is running the dotnet command from there.
Do I install .NET on the D: drive also or something else?
Thanks*

Turns out it was an outdated video.

Comment: You need to add the `dotnet` binary to your PATH environment variable. Google that and you should have no problem working with .NET Core afterwards.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the command you are using? My first guess is you likely need to use the full path to the files on D: drive but you may already be doing that.

Comment: No environment variables are system level not drive level. Have you verified that dotnet is in your path? If you don't know what that means you can use the search string "check if app is in my windows path"

Comment: The dotnet binary is already in the path and I was following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4heVCEe3u8) at about 8 mins is where I'm up to.

Comment: So I just changed the workspace to the C: drive and got the same error. So I'm thinking that it's just Visual Studio Code that doesn't recognize the "dotnet new" command.

Comment: post the exact error message you get when you type `dotnet new` or `dotnet`. just saying "it is unrecognized" is too vague.

Comment: The presence of two drives is not relevant.  The first comment tells you what is wrong.  You do not have `dotnet` in your PATH.

Comment: @LSmith you mention a couple of software?  Which version of .NET Core do you have installed? And Which version  of Visual Code do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

On my new machine, I just literally install the latest Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.400.(No reboot)

Open a command prompt, navigated to a folder on my C: drive and did the following command:

```
dotnet new -n C_drive_project
```

[image: C Drive - dotnew]

Navigated to folder on E: drive, perform the following command:

```
dotnet new mvc -n E_drive_project
```

[image: E Drive - dotnet]

You can also get information about your installation with `dotnet --info`
[image: dotnet information]